# Preserve Login Session on Android

Tags: php, android, cookies, session-cookies

I'm working on app that needs to preserve a Login Session through a server..
On first try I ask to user to authenticate, look up if username/password is right and save Cookie to go on through my session to download file..
So I have no problem at all for moment, but now I'm wondering, if I want to don't ask again to user to input username/password combinatio, what is best thing to do:
Save Cookie and then Restore
or
Save Username/Password and everytime User opens app make a httpget to server and recreate my session?
Thank you

**EDIT**
I'm just wondering which is best.. Save Cookie or Save Username/Password?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) Class.
On Successful login, it stores the user credentials into `SharedPreference` as follows,

To store values in SharedPreference

```
SharedPreferences sPrefs = getSharedPreferences("loginData", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPrefs.edit();
editor.putString("userName", "value");
editor.putString("password", "value");
editor.commit();
```

To retrieve values from SharedPreference,

```
SharedPreferences sPrefs = getSharedPreferences("loginData", 0);
String userName = sPrefs.getString("userName", "default value");
String password = sPrefs.getString("password", "default value");
```

Comment: why not simply store cookie information returned from the server on first login, instead of saving username and password ?

Comment: Just to make thigns clear: Save Coookie trough SharedPreferences and add Every Value that I got from getCookies() and then to restore, in my httpclient I add through HttpContext?

Comment: @AntonioCalì Yes that's fine, It is like instead of saving two items(username & password) in SharedPreference, a single item ( cookie value ) would be better option :)

Answer (score 1):

Just save the cookie information into your Shared Preferences in private mod, and check for the saved cookie information on the onCreate method of Login activity. If the cookie information is present in Shared Preferences, then ask your server to restore the session and move the user to next screen without promoting for username/password